# Python model persistence without pickling

Tags: python, predictive-modeling

Are there any Python machine learning libraries, which allow model persistence without pickling?

More specifically, I want to avoid problems (and time sinks) that could arise upon sharing models with others. (In my case: academic collaborators in non-computational research fields.)

Comment: This might be the right time to go enterprisey and [investigate](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/1596) [PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml). Personally I just save the model parameters, like so https://cmry.github.io/notes/serialize

Comment: @Emre : thank you for your suggestions of potential work-arounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to export the model to [Predictive Model Markup Language (PMML)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictive_Model_Markup_Language) format.

In scikit-learn, [sklearn2pmml](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) can be used.